# CoreData Parent Child

Tags: core-data, swiftui

**Goal:** I am trying to have a list of continents that when you click on show the list of countries in that continent using CoreData.

**Current:** Whenever I add a new country it adds an untitled continent object & all countries show up in all continents.

I currently have two entities: Continent & Country, both only have a single attribute: Continent.title & Country.name. Continent is set as the parent entity of Country.

**Tried:** In the coreData model editor I set continent as the parent entity of country & I set the country relationship to continent. Neither solved the issue.

### Code:

**Continent View:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Continent.title, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Continent>



var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(item.name ?? "Title", destination: Countries(title: item.name ?? "Title"))
            }

            //for adding new continents
            newContinent()
            
        }.navigationTitle("Continents")
        
    }
}
}
```

**newContinent():**

```
struct newContinent : View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@State var place = ""

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        TextField("Add New Place", text: $place)
    
        Button(action: {
            let newItem = Continent(context: viewContext)
            newItem.title = place
            saveContext()
            
            place = ""
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
                .foregroundColor(place == "" ? .gray : .white)
        }).disabled(place == "")
    }        
}


func saveContext() {
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

}

**Country View:**

```
struct Countries: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Country.name, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
private var countries: FetchedResults<Country>

let title: String

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List{
            ForEach(countries) { item in
                Text(item.name!)
            }
            newCountry()
        }
    }.navigationTitle(title)
    
}
}
```

**NewCountry():**

```
struct newCountry : View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@State var place = ""

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        TextField("Add New Country", text: $place)
    
        Button(action: {
            let newItem = Country(context: viewContext)
            newItem.name = place
            saveContext()
            
            place = ""
        }, label: {
            Text("Save")
                .foregroundColor(place == "" ? .gray : .primary)
        }).disabled(place == "")
    }  
}


func saveContext() {
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you create a new country object it should be assigned to an existing continent, don't you think? So either have an already selected continent be sent to your view for creating countries or have a list of continents to select from in that view.

Comment: And I noticed you wrote "parent" above, I hope you don't mean the "Parent Entity" attribute in Xcode because that is not what you should use here but only relationships.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - When I send the already selected continent to the countries view do I set continent as an attribute in country entity?

Comment: Yes, the attribute has the name you gave the relationship

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I passed `Continent` to my country view as a property without `FetchedResults` then I set it to `country.continent` which is the relationship. In my country view I then filtered all countries for `country.continent` & only showed the ones satisfying that condition. It seems to work now. Thank you for your help.